# Kafka Docker Image wont Run when Security protocol is PLAINTEXT

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm pretty new to Docker, and am trying to run a Kafka docker image that has a security protocol of plaintext. I know this security protocol exists and works, because I can get my container running with `docker-compose up` in a directory containing a compose file with the environment variables defined. However, I am having a hard time getting the image running via command line.

I am running this command in terminal:

```
docker run -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT='zookeeper:2181' -e KAFKA_LISTENERS='PLAINTEXT://:81543,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:33333' --name kafka sha256:c3b05sdaw30e711c09b925e52991cc0a9c0c163016fhd47ae39840f255f490b2
```

My kafka env variables in my compose file is:

```
environment:
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:81543,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:33333
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:81543,PLAINTEXT_HOST://host.docker.internal:33333
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from ''PLAINTEXT://:81543,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:33333'': No security protocol defined for listener 'PLAINTEXT
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:274)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.$anonfun$listeners$1(KafkaConfig.scala:1680)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.listeners(KafkaConfig.scala:1679)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.advertisedListeners(KafkaConfig.scala:1707)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1778)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1756)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1312)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:68)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No security protocol defined for listener 'PLAINTEXT
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.$anonfun$createEndPoint$2(EndPoint.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.getOrElse(Map.scala:530)
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.securityProtocol$1(EndPoint.scala:48)
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.createEndPoint(EndPoint.scala:53)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.$anonfun$listenerListToEndPoints$6(CoreUtils.scala:271)
        at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:86)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.map(ArraySeq.scala:38)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:271)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to define all my config variables in the command like this:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

```
docker run --network=rmoff_kafka --rm --detach --name broker \
           -p 9092:9092 \
           -e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1 \
           -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 \
           -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 \
           -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
           confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
```